# php and javascript date not match

Tags: php, javascript, datetime

i have a strange questions.
In my php page i try to print dates with php function and javascript function.
My code is:

```
// 04 09 2013 09:47:28
<script>document.write(new Date());</script>
// 04 09 2013 09:48:17
<?php echo date('d m Y H:i:s');?>
```

Why the dates are not equal, but there is a litte second of difference?

I would have same dates beetween php and javascript.

**---UPDATE CODE---**

```
function startCounter(){
    start = new Date(<?php echo time(); ?> * 1000);
    end = new Date(<?php echo $end_ts; ?> * 1000);
    timer = setInterval(updateCounter, refreshInterval);
}

function updateCounter(){
var now = new Date();
    var distance = new Date(end - now);
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: time difference between your server and the computer your browser lives on?

Comment: Are JavaScript and PHP executed in the same computer?

Comment: Javascript in my browser, php in remote server

Comment: @Mike - So you've just answered your question. Most clocks are not atomic clocks ;-)

Comment: @Mike - Your question has already been answered. Please don't edit it to ask a new question, use the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button instead. (Though you haven't really asked a question, you've merely posted some code.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to understand the time being printed by php is the server time and time being printed by javascript is your local computer time. If the time between those 2 is different then it can show different time.

Comment: Add to that the time it takes for the server to actually _send_ the page over to the client, who will then render the page, parse the JS, and execute the code, and you'll _never_ get the exact same time, even if both clocks were set to the same time

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, javascript time is client time and php time is server time.
To solve the problem try something simliar to:

```
<? $time = time(); ?>
<script>document.write(new Date(<?=$time*1000?>));</script>    
<?=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time')?>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`... just don't

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I totally agree with you. I just copied the authors code :)